# Create a directory and move files into it

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

I am taking screenshots using selenium for my cucumber test. I want one of my steps to place a screenshot file in a folder with a folder name generated using input from the step + time stamp.

Here is what I have accomplished so far:

```
Then /^screen shots are placed in the folder "(.*)"$/ do |folder_name|
    time = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    source ="screen_shots"
    destination = "screen_shots\_#{folder_name}_#{time}"

    if !Dir.exists? destination
        Dir.new destination

    end
    Dir.glob(File.join(source, '*')).each do |file|

        if File.exists? (file)

                File.move file, File.join(destination, File.basename(file))
        end
    end
end
```

If the directory does not exist, I want to create it. Then I want to place all screenshots into the new directory.

The folder is to be created in the same directory as the screenshots and then all screenshot files are to be moved into the folder. I am still learning ruby, and my attempts to put this together are not working out at all:

`Desktop > cucumber_project_folder > screenshots_folder > shot1.png, shot2.png`

In short, I want to create a new directory in `screenshots` and move `shot1.png` and `shot2.png` into it.  How can I do so?

Based on the answer given this is the solution (for cucumber)

```
Then /^screen shots are placed in the folder "(.*)" contained in "(.*)"$/ do |folder_name, source_path|
  date_time = Time.now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
  source = Pathname.new(source_path)
  destination = source + "#{folder_name}_#{date_time}"
  destination.mkdir unless destination.exist?
  files = source.children.find_all { |f| f.file? and f.fnmatch?('*.png') }
  FileUtils.move(files, destination)
end
```

The source path is indicated in the step so different users do not have to modify the definition.

Comment: You should look [**FileUtils**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir_p) and try it by yourself..Its very easy.. all can be done using this stdlib.. :))

Comment: StackOverflow is a great place to ask questions, but you shouldn't expect us to do the work for you. Show us what you've got and what isn't working and we'll try to help you through it -- but as @Priti says, this is pretty simple to write using the Ruby standard library.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep in mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on with your first line of code

```
Then /^screen shots are placed in the folder "(.*)"$/ do |folder_name|
```

as it's not Ruby code, but I've made it work with a notional line from a file.

- The `Pathname` class allows things like `destination.exist?` instead of `File.exist?(destination)`. It also lets you build composite paths with `+` and provides the `children` method.
- The `FileUtils` module provides the `move` facility.
- Note that Ruby allows forward slashes to be used in Windows paths, and it is usually easier to use them instead of having to escape backslashes everywhere.

I've also added a hyphen between the date and the time in the directory name, as otherwise it's pretty much unreadable.

```
require 'pathname'
require 'fileutils'

source = Pathname.new('C:/my/source')

line = 'screen shots are placed in the folder "screenshots"'

/^screen shots are placed in the folder "(.*)"$/.match(line) do |m|

  folder_name = m[1]
  date_time = Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')

  destination = source + "#{folder_name}_#{date_time}"
  destination.mkdir unless destination.exist?
  jpgs = source.children.find_all { |f| f.file? and f.fnmatch?('*.jpg') }
  FileUtils.move(jpgs, destination)

end
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed this a little to get it to work. The first line is Gherkin as I mentioned I am writing this for cucumber test. I will post my modifications.